# Can I get slope of three columns of a dataframe and create a new column with the values in python?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, linear-regression

does anyone know how to calculate the slope of three columns (y-axis) given a fixed x-axis for every row?
For example, this is my dataframe:

```
data = {'a':  [1, 2, 3],
        'b': [3, 4, 5],
        'c': [7, 8, 9]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

What I need is to create a fourth column 'd' with the slopes of 1, 3, and 7, considering the x axis to be, for example, 1, 2, and 3. This 1, 2, 3 x-axis, should be considered for every row of data.

Comment: The slope definition is for two points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`. Do you mean the slope of a liner line passing  through `(1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 7)` for example?

Comment: actually I need a slope defined by a simple linear regression of three points (1,3,7) and (1,2,3);   (2,4,5) and (1,2,3);    (3,5,9) and (1,2,3)

Comment: for example, a simple linear regression (x1, x2, x3) = (1,2,3) and (y1, y2, y3) = (1, 3, 7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you can use `np.polyfit()` to find the slope ( by defining the degree of polynomial to 1) and then compute `d` and put it in your dictionary and finally convert it to a `pandas DataFrame`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def compute_slope(arr):
    return round(np.polyfit([1, 2, 3], arr, 1)[0], 2)

data = {'a':  [1, 2, 3],
        'b': [3, 4, 5],
        'c': [7, 8, 9]}

data['d'] = [compute_slope(list(arr)) for arr in zip(data['a'], data['b'], data['c'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

The variable `[1,2,3]` in the `compute_slope` function is hard coded because you mentioned you want to have x values like that.

Output:

```py
   a  b  c    d
0  1  3  7  3.0
1  2  4  8  3.0
2  3  5  9  3.0
```